# Inserting variable into regex (JavaScript) isn't working

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my code:

```
var newLT = 'locTable'+(l+locations);
var findLT = 'locTable'+l;
var regex = new RegExp("/\b" + findLT + "\b/g");
locOrig = locOrig.replace(regex, newLT);
```

I'm trying to replace all instances of 'locTable(#number here)' with the newLT variable.

So for example if this was in a string `<input id="locTable3_0">` ideally I could replace just the 'locTable3' part which is stored in findLT with the value in newLT.

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: For clarity:

Say I have the string `<input id="locTable3_0">`.

variable `newLT` is equal to locTable4

variable `findLT` is equal to locTable3

I want to have a regex which finds locTable3 and replaces it with locTable4 so that my resulting string is `<input id="locTable4_0">`

Comment: You don't need the beginning and ending `/`s when using the RegExp constructor.

Comment: Removing those isn't fixing anything unfortunately. Any idea what else the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

Updated: I think I god it now

```
var regex = /locTable\d/;
var newString = 'something_else_3'
var string = "locTable3_0";
var result = string.replace(regex1, newString);
```

this will result in `something_else_3_0`

Comment: Sorry I guess I was unclear. I have updated the original post with a better example

Comment: Updated to replace the first part of the match. I'm ignoring the second part ('_0')

Answer (score 0):

- /.../xyz is short notation, that won't work here

`new RegExp("/\b" + findLT + "\b/g");` => `new RegExp("\b" + findLT + "\b", "g");`

- You are passing string to RegExp constructor, so you have to escape special chars twice:

`new RegExp("\b" + findLT + "\b", "g");` => `new RegExp("\\b" + findLT + "\\b", "g");`

Comment: +1. `/…/` is a [*Regular Expression Literal*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.5).

Comment: This is very close but it still will not swap out locTable# (with # being an integer) when it is followed by _#, what needs to be added for this?